# Avalonia Button in DataGrid is always disabled

Tags: c#, button, datagrid, avalonia

I have a `DataGrid` that has one column for buttons.
The button is visible, however I cannot click on it for some reason. The button looks disabled, even if I set the `IsEnabled` property to true.

```xml
<Grid>
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False" 
              Items="{Binding Players}">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
             [Some other columns...]
             <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=""
                                     Width="100">
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <StackPanel>
                             <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsDummy}"
                                     IsVisible="{Binding IsDummy}"
                                     Command="{Binding ToDoFunction}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                                  Recruit
                              </Button>
                         </StackPanel>
                     </DataTemplate> 
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>   
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Any idea or suggestion ?

Tried to change the bindings, but they look ok. Tried to enable/disable the datagrid, no effect

Comment: Have you tried to set IsReadOnly to False?

Comment: I tried, did not work. However, I found the mistake. Contrarily to what my IDE told me, the bindings were not ok...